# Array addition in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, addition

Having trouble with the last `for` loop. Want the total of the array values.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Arrays

int main()
{
    const int numEmploye = 6;
    int horas[numEmploye];
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmploye; i++) {
        cout << "entre las horas trabajadas por el empleado " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> horas[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numEmploye; i++) {
        cout << horas[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmploye; i++){
        cout << total += numEmploye[i];
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting the return value of the += operator. You're also using the wrong variable for the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numEmploye; i++){
    total += horas[i];
}
cout << total << endl; // endl flushes the buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following, which prints the value of total += numEmploye[i]; numEmploye times...

```
for (int i = 0; i < numEmploye; i++){
    cout << total += numEmploye[i];
}
```

... calculate the total first and then print that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numEmploye; i++){
    total += horas[i];
}
cout << total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as of C++11 you can use one of these options:

```
#include <numeric>
 ...
int total = std::accumulate(std::begin(horas), std::end(horas), 0);
std::cout << total << std::endl;
```

or

```
for (int i : horas)
    total += i;
std::cout << total << std::endl;
```